# On Windows, how do you direct console output to file from batch file when invoked by clicking?

Tags: windows, redirect, command-line

I am running a Tomcat instance by clicking on startup.bat as opposed to invoking the batch file from the command prompt. When I do this, a window with output appears which I would like to capture to a file. Can this be done in any other way than from the command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another bat file [for example start_tomcat.bat] which will call the original bat file that you mentioned above.
The content of that file could be:

```
start.bat > yourfilename.txt
```

*where "start.bat" is your original file that you start your Tomcat instance*

You can redirect any output of any command to a file by using the ">" character.
For example :

```
echo HelloWorld > myfile.txt
```